# how to free local storage memory?

Tags: html, local-storage

Could any one tell me how to free the localstorage on DOM WEB Storage

I have populated the localstorage like the following: `localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));`

Now i want unset the space used for the same. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use:

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

or remove everything:

```
localStorage.clear();
```